# google translate API Japanese detection

Tags: java, google-api-java-client

I have an web application using google translate API. It developed in java using google-api-services-translate. 
It has some problem translate Japanese to another language. Actually write in Japanese pronunciation like a "Sayonara".

I tried translate "Sayonara" on translate.google.com. Its result is "farewell".
but my application's result is "Sayonara"

For Example (using cUrl),

> $ curl -X POST -H"Content-Type:application/json" -d"{\"texts\":[\"sayonara\"],\"target\":\"en\"}" http://127.0.0.1/translate

result is,

> [{"detectedSourceLanguage":"ja","translatedText":"sayonara"}]

Another example,

> $ curl -X POST -H"Content-Type:application/json" -d"{\"texts\":[\"さよなら\"],\"target\":\"en\"}" http://127.0.0.1/translate

result is,

> [{"detectedSourceLanguage":"ja","translatedText":"Farewell"}]

How can I get a result "Farewell"?

using java source is,

```
public List list(java.util.List<java.lang.String> q, java.lang.String target) throws java.io.IOException {
  List result = new List(q, target);
  initialize(result);
  return result;
}
//----------------------------------------------------
Translate translate = builder.build();
Translate.Translations.List list = translate.translations().list(req.texts, req.target);
```

Comment: I've tried to inspect some of the data which the translate page sends. It would seem that if I type in `Sayonara`, `さよなら` gets also transmitted. So it might be that you need actual Japanese characters to get it to work.

Comment: @npinti yes, google translate page works fine. but through java api works not properly

Comment: What I mean is that even through the google translate page, it is transmitting Japanese text together with the English text version.